# get cell data with loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

[image: 1]

hello,
I have a DataFrame with month, year and mean_rep
I'm trying to get the mean_rep for 09/2021
I wrote this line as part of the code:

```
rep = df_rep.loc[(df_rep['months'] == month) & (df_rep['years'] == year), 'mean_rep'].values
```

and it comes back as an empty list
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: if it came back as an empty list it means your conditions are wrong maybe the dtypes don't match?

Comment: how can I make sure the dtypes match?

Comment: `print(df.dtypes)` then if its an object (a string) then you need to pass it as a string i.e `'1' != 1` but rather `'1' == '1'` also please read [mcve] and [ask] an image is not acceptable for an example.

Comment: Thank you and sorry

Comment: @m_n can you paste the output from `df.dtypes` and `df.head()` into the question? that will help you get an answer because currently we can't reproduce your problem